# On average, how many times must a 6-sided die be rolled until a 6 turns up twice in a row?

Tags: probability, dice

On average, how many times must a 6-sided die be rolled until a 6 turns up twice in a row?

This  a question from "a collection of dice problem", the original explanation I couldn't understant. Can someone explain it from the expectation (sum of an infinite series) point of view?

Comment: The most straightforward way, I think, is to condition on the result of the first toss and (if it a $6$) conditioning on the result of the second toss. Is this the type of approach you are referring to, that you don't understand?

Comment: The solution depends on what you were first taught and are most comfortable with.  You can describe this as a three-state absorbing markov chain with states (Second6inarow),(First6inarow),(Not6) and corresponding transition matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1& \frac{1}{6}&0 \\0 &0&\frac{1}{6} \\0& \frac{5}{6}& \frac{5}{6}\end{bmatrix}$.  [The fundamental matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Fundamental_matrix) will tell you information about the expected time it takes to roll the die to reach the absorbing state.  This is the way I personally think.

Comment: Have you read about any of the probability distributions? Expected values?

Comment: Hi RonaldB, Could you explain it from Expected value point of view (sum of infinity series)